# MVC Controller called again after redirecting to another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, controller, http-status-code-302

I am building an e-commerce application using the [eWay](https://www.eway.com.au) payment portal and I've run into an odd issue.

In my setup for eWay, I am giving a redirect URL for the payment gateway to use to come back to my application. This works correctly and at the end of the callback method I am using `RedirectToAction` to redirect to a `Confirmation` view.

However, after the callback method completes, it is called again. Only the second time will the redirect to my confirmation page complete properly.

Looking in Fiddler I appear to get a correct `302` response from my callback method to my confirmation view, however I get an icon that is the `Session was aborted by the client, Fiddler, or the Server`. Note that this still occurs when Fiddler is closed.

My callback method:

```
public ActionResult PurchaseCallback(string accessCode)
{
    // payment processing
    .....

    return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
}

public ActionResult Confirmation()
{
    return View("Confirmation");
}
```

Fiddler trace:

[image]

Fiddler trace showing request and response headers:

[image]

Note the call to `/Purchase/Purchase` which redirects to the eWay portal, before the tunnel to eWay itself, before returning to `Purchase/PurchaseCallback` twice before finally arriving at `/Purchase/Confirmation`. Also note the icon on the first `/PurchaseCallback` call, which indicates an aborted session. However I don't know why it would be aborted.

There is no associated view for `PurchaseCallback` and the view for `Confirmation` has no JavaScript or other requests. I am using IIS Express, but I am using the `RedirectToAction` pattern in many other places without issue.

What would be causing my controller method to be called twice, and how can I stop it happening?

Comment: That would entirely depend on the client-side code you've got

Comment: @Rob, as I mentioned, there's is no client side code dealing with redirects or other requests after the return from eWay.

Comment: I don't think we are able to see both inbound and outbond packets on that trace right?  Can you show us both?

Comment: @JohnPeters I'm not sure what you mean. The highlighted request is coming in from eWay and showing the redirect to the correct page in the response.

Comment: The trace is only showing us inbound requests to the server, we can't see the responses.

Comment: RedirectToAction Method (String, String)  Try this method and specify the controller too.

Comment: @JohnPeters I've added another image showing the request and response headers. The request is the top right and the response is the bottom left. You can see the response is to `/Purchase/Confirmation` but then it calls `PurchaseCallback` again.

Comment: @JohnPeters, I actually already had that since I continued through adding a parameters to the request, same problem.

Comment: Do you have auto-redirect enabled in the eWAY Shared Page settings? I've sometimes found this can result in an additional request to the return URL.

Comment: @JohnC wow, that was it. I had the "auto redirect" option enabled which apparently sent two requests even when clicking the "finalise" button on the eWay page. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have the "Redirect after payment processing" option enabled in you eWAY Shared Page settings ([doco here](https://go.eway.io/s/article/How-to-return-to-my-site-automatically-after-using-the-responsive-shared-page?language=en_US)). Sometimes this can create a call to the redirect page before/just after you've clicked on the button, which would create two calls (this is particularly a problem if the delay is set to 5 seconds).

Comment: This was exactly the answer, I even had the delay set to 5 seconds.